# Highest level of .Net Framework \ Visual Studio to Run ASP.Net Web apps on Windows 2000 Server?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, windows-server-2000

What is the highest level of .Net Framework and\or version of Visual Studio to develop and run ASP.Net Web applications for the Windows 2000 Advanced Server SP4 operating system?

I want to use the most current technology possible to develop such a visual studio 2008 but unfortunately a client can provide a Win2K server to deploy and run the applications on.  I understand that VS2008 can target the .Net 2.0 framework for deployment and that .Net 2.0 can run on Win2k SP4 but I am looking for confirmation that this will actually work from the community.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will work (2.0 is the highest version that will work on Windows 2000).